# Creating and Executing SQL Queries Dynamically from Python in SQL Server Machine Learning Service

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

in SQL Machine Learning Services I want to define an SQL query in a Python script and then execute this query in the rest of the T-SQL script.

I am writing a program in SQL Server Machine Learning Service. The Python code will return an SQL query in a variable. After that, I need to execute it in T-SQL.

Here's an example, but the problem is that no temporary table is being created. Here's the example:

```
DECLARE @script NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
DECLARE @x1 NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- Python code to define the value of @x1
EXEC sp_execute_external_script
    @language = N''Python'',
    @script = N''
x1 = "CREATE TABLE #test (ID INT,Nom VARCHAR(50),Age INT)"
'',
    @params = N''@x1 NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT'',
    @x1 = @x1 OUTPUT;

-- Using @x1 in the rest of the T-SQL script
EXEC sp_executesql @x1;
'

EXEC sp_executesql @script;
```

Comment: Temporary table cannot escape the scope of the dynamic sql that creates it. Your question sounds a bit confused in general, it's probably better you explain *what* you're trying to achieve without using code

Comment: @siggemannen My Python code will allow me to know the number and names of the columns in the temporary table, which is why the Python code will return a string containing an SQL query. Then, I have to execute this query in T-SQL.

Comment: I get that, but why,this is a strange way of communicating outputs. You can use json or whatever. Plus, python won't be able to populate that table. And finally, like I wrote, once dynamic sql finishes the table is gone. Read about output parameters in sp_execute_external_script and see if you can use something else